# Apache processes linger around despite all

Tags: apache, io, timeout

I am running into a baffling issue with Apache. For two times already it would just stall, hit the MaxClients setting (33 as witnessed below) and stops accepting new requests.

```
Apache Timeout 30 sec
KeepAliveTimeout 2 sec
PHP max_execution_time 30 sec
mysql connect_timeout 10 sec (no problems there, kept serving other clients)
```

Apache version 2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
mod_php

What am I missing here? What would convince Apache to have the processes linger around like that? Is there any way to limit the "wall clock" time for Apache processes? Apache restart is the cure, but I would still prefer to know the underlying issue..

ps auxf, taken 14:30, so processes have been stuck for over 30 minutes!

```
root     25963  0.0  0.3 273860 12656 ?        Ss   May04   6:43 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15120  0.1  1.0 289684 44872 ?        S    13:56   0:03  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15301  0.0  0.9 290644 41624 ?        S    13:57   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15392  0.1  1.0 290636 43800 ?        S    13:57   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15570  0.0  0.9 287508 40512 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15575  0.0  0.9 290684 41528 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15576  0.1  1.0 290612 45080 ?        S    13:58   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15581  0.1  0.9 290684 41420 ?        S    13:58   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15582  0.0  0.9 288508 40124 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15583  0.1  0.9 288500 40640 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15584  0.0  1.0 290592 43832 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15593  0.1  1.0 289444 41956 ?        S    13:58   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15669  0.0  1.0 290432 42312 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15754  0.0  1.0 289200 42468 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15788  0.1  1.0 290580 42068 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15789  0.0  0.9 290428 41088 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15790  0.0  0.9 290488 41004 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15792  0.0  0.8 285756 35944 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15793  0.0  0.9 290488 40880 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15794  0.1  1.0 290508 44920 ?        S    13:58   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15799  0.0  0.8 285796 36540 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15800  0.0  0.9 290432 40940 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15801  0.0  0.8 285604 36128 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15802  0.1  0.9 290556 41548 ?        S    13:58   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15803  0.0  0.9 290660 41140 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15804  0.1  0.9 288068 40104 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15805  0.0  0.8 284796 33744 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15806  0.0  0.9 290344 40744 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15811  0.0  0.9 290412 41060 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15812  0.1  1.1 291668 47908 ?        S    13:58   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15813  0.0  0.9 290512 40980 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15814  0.0  0.9 289348 40912 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15815  0.0  0.9 290508 40908 ?        S    13:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15816  0.0  0.9 290508 41020 ?        S    13:58   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and I've been dealing with a very similar problem. I've been running a site on AWS t2.micro which has only 1 gig of memory. Like you the site would "stall". It would take 30 seconds for the php index page to render.  I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 with Postgres as the database.

I figured out that apache was not really the problem. If I stopped postgres, then apache would serve the pages quickly, albeit without data. But it certainly pointed to postgres was the culprit. Apache processes were waiting for Postgres queries so I would see a lot of Apache2 processes lingering. Feels like a Postgres memory leak, but hard to nail down.

I upgraded to the t2.small instance on AWS which has 2 gigs of memory. So far so good as no problems yet. Keeping fingers crossed.